# Rails & Twilio: Receiving nil when storing texts received from Twilio

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, twilio

I have set up the request URL in my Twilio account to have it POST to: myurl.com/receivetext. It appears to be successfully posting because when I check the database using the Heroku console I see the following:

Post id: 5, body: nil, from: nil, created_at: "2012-06-14 17:28:01", updated_at: "2012-06-14 17:28:01"

Why is it receiving nil for the body and from attributes? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong! The created and updated at are storing successfully but the two attributes that I care about continue to be stored as nil.

Here's the Receive Text controller which is receiving the Post request from Twilio:

```
class ReceiveTextController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @post=Post.create!(body: params[:Body], from: params[:From])
  end
end
```

EDIT: When I dump the params I receive the following: 
"{\"controller\"=>\"receive_text\", \"action\"=>\"index\"}"

I attained this by inserting the following into my ReceiveText controller. @params = Post.create!(body: params.inspect, from: "Dumping Params") and then opening up the Heroku console to find the database entry with from = "Dumping Params".

I simulated a Twilio request with a curl with the following command curl -X POST myurl.com/receivetext route -d 'AccountSid=AC123&From=%2B19252411234'

I checked the production database again and noticed that the curl request did work when obtaining the FROM atribute. It stored the following:

params.inspect returned "{\"AccountSid\"=>\"AC123\", \"From\"=>\"+19252411234\", \"co..."

I received a comment stating: "As long as twilio is hitting the same URL with the same method (GET/POST) it should be filling the params array as well" I have no idea how to make this comment actionable. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm very new to rails.

Here's my database migration (I have both attributes set to string. I have tried setting it to text and that didn't work either) :

```
 class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
    t.string :body
    t.string :from

    t.timestamps
   end
  end
 end
```

Here is my Post model:

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :body, :from
 end
```

Routes (everything appears to be routing just fine) :

```
 MovieApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "receive_text/index"
  get "pages/home"
  get "send_text/send_text_message"


  root to: 'pages#home'

  match '/receivetext', to: 'receive_text#index'
  match '/pages/home', to: 'pages#home'
  match '/sendtext', to: 'send_text#send_text_message'
 end
```

Here's my gemfile (incase it helps)

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

  gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
  gem 'badfruit'
  gem 'twilio-ruby'
  gem 'logger'
  gem 'jquery-rails'


 group :production do
  gem 'pg'
 end

 group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
 end


 group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to make this a `create` action that's called [via `POST`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request)?

```
class ReceiveTextController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.create!(body: params[:Body], from: params[:From])
  end
end
```

And in your `routes.rb`:

```
post "receive_text/create"
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. I just realized that the Twilio request isn't even being sent to the application at all. The "nil" I was saving to the database was a result of me manually visiting the application link "http://myapp.com/receivetext" thus triggering nil for :From & :Body and storing created_at & updated at for the time at which I manually visited the link.

Comment: Should I leave the GET alone and additionally add the Post? I deleted it and replaced it with POST in the routes file.

Comment: Just figured it out! Turns out I was typing the POST url in a new App that I created in my twilio account instead of pasting the uRL in the "Test your app" sandbox section.